# Get Name List of all running processes windows

Tags: c++

I want to get list of all running processes like following

```
example.exe
example2.exe
```

so on...
heres code what ive tried

```
WCHAR* GetAllRunningProccess()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
        TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0
    );

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    Process32First(snap, &pe32);

    do {
        return  pe32.szExeFile;
    } while (Process32Next(snap, &pe32));
}
    std::wcout << GetAllRunningProccess() << std::endl;
```

it only prints

```
[System Process]
```

Comment: What do you expect `do { return ... } while (..)` to do, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have written does **not** work like a generator function to *yield* multiple values.  It just exits when returning the first value.  You cannot return from a function more than once.

```
do {
   return ...; // This will both exit the loop and exit the function.
} while(...);
```

Although, [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) offer `co_yield` to accomplish this.

#### To fix...

The most basic repair would be to redesign your function to return a `vector` of strings rather than just a single string.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> GetAllRunningProcesses()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
        TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0
    );

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    Process32First(snap, &pe32);

    std::vector<std::string> result;
    do {
        result.push_back(pe32.szExeFile);
    } while (Process32Next(snap, &pe32));
    CloseHandle(snap);
    return result;
}
```

Then, to call it, you could use something like this:

```
for (const auto& processName : GetAllRunningProcesses()) {
   std::cout << processName << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: kk ill try right now! thanks for the response

Comment: Don't forget proper error handling of system calls. `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, `Process32First()`, `Process32Next()` could fail, so be sure to handle that properly. And don't forget to `CloseHandle()` the snapshot `HANDLE` when you are done using it. And just for the record, MSDN has an example showing how to use these exact functions: [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes).

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
do {
        return  pe32.szExeFile;
    } while (Process32Next(snap, &pe32));
```

Am pretty sure after executing this while loop once the compiler is returning one value then exiting the function and continues executing the code in main body rather then going back to the loop, hence getting only 1 output(one process).

Update your Code accordingly and then test.

Comment: @Wyck I have updated it hope its clear now